# whats wrong with my javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why it wont work. it wont count calculate total. The total it return the array instead of the total of the number in the array.

```js
function calculate() {
  var num = prompt("How many number : ");
  var number = [];
  var i = 0,
    count, count1, total, total1;

  while (i < num) {
    number.push(prompt("Enter a number :"));

    if (number[i] > 5) {
      count = count + 1;
      total = total + number[i];
    } else if (number[i] <= 5) {
      count1 = count1 + 1;
      total1 = total1 + number[i];
    }
    i++;

  }

  document.write("For count >5 ", count);
  document.write("For total >5 ", total);
  document.write("For count <=5 ", count1);
  document.write("For total >5 ", total1);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>
  <button onclick="calculate()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

i dont know what i do wrong.. i need help.

Comment: I don't see where it returns an _array_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

```js
function calculate() {
  var num = prompt("How many number : ");
  var number = [];
  var i = 0,
    count=0, count1=0, total=0, total1=0;

  while (i < num) {
    number.push(prompt("Enter a number :"));

    if (parseInt(number[i]) > 5) {
      count++;
      total = total + parseInt(number[i]);
    } else if (parseInt(number[i]) <= 5) {
      count1++;
      total1 = total1 + parseInt(number[i]);
    }
    i++;

  }

  document.write("For count >5 is ", count,"</br>");
  document.write("For total >5 is  ", total,"</br>");
  document.write("For count <=5 is " , count1,"</br>");
  document.write("For total >5 is ", total1,"</br>");
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>
  <button onclick="calculate()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just a minor suggestion but would it not be a little cleaner if you store `parseInt(number[i]);` in a variable and refer to that rather than using `parseInt();` over and over for the same value?

Comment: @NewToJS sure buddy, will take care from next time :)